# Vue Js v-model not working with array created in Laravel model

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm currently in the process of building a CMS using Laravel and Vue JS which build forms dynamically based on an array of data created in the Laravel model. Here is an example:

```
class TheBuilding extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [...];

    public function formFields(){
        $fields = [
            [
                'label' => 'Title',
                'name' => 'title',
                'component' => 'input_text'
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Content',
                'name' => 'content',
                'component' => 'input_textarea'
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Main Image',
                'name' => 'main_image',
                'component' => 'input_single_upload'
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Gallery',
                'name' => 'gallery',
                'component' => 'input_multiple_upload',
                'meta' => [
                    [
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'name' => 'caption',
                        'label' => 'Caption'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ];
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Basically this array gets passed into Vue JS and parsed to dynamically display Vue JS form components accordingly. This has been working great but I've come across an interesting issue with the Gallery multiple upload component which needs the ability to assign captions to images.

To fast forward a bit, I'm at the point where I have an array of uploaded files which get iterated through and displayed on the page, and then I have the input textfield for the caption underneath.

Here's my component (edited to show the relevant bits):

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
       <div v-for="(file, i) in files">
            <img :src="file.file" >
            <div v-for="meta in file.meta">
                <input v-if="meta.type == 'text'" type="text" v-model="meta.value">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        computed:{
            files(){
                let uploads = [];
                /*this.uploaded is just an array of filenames*/
                this.uploaded.forEach((file, i) => {
                    let createdMeta = [
                        {
                            name:"caption",
                            type:"text",
                            value:''
                        }
                    ];
                    uploads.push({file,meta:createdMeta});
                });
                return uploads;
            }
        },
        props:{ ... },
        mounted(){
            //CODE THAT HANDLES DROPZONE UPLOAD
        },
        name: 'InputMultipleUpload',
        data(){
            return {
                showUploadProgress:true,
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The bit I'm focusing on is:

```
let createdMeta = [{
    name:"caption",
    type:"text",
    value:''
}];
```

You'll notice here that I've created that array statically. If I do that, when I type in a caption textbox everything works fine and the caption value gets updated dynamically by v-model as expected. Essentially, I get the desired result and everything is good.

However, if I try and set this this dynamically from the created model ie:

```
let createdMeta = formFields;
```

where formFields is the reference to the model array, when I then type in the textbox it updates all other textboxes and values in the files array created. V-Model no longer seems to relate to the specific textbox.

So I guess the question I'm asking is:

a) Why is it behaving that way when I passed in the referenced array

b) Why does it work fine if I just manually create that array?

c) How can I get A to behave like B?

Thanks everyone, happy to clarify anything. I assume i'm missing a piece in the reactivity puzzle.

Cheers,
Lew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `data` not `computed`.

Try something like this:

```
<script>
  export default {
    props: {...},
    mounted () {
      //CODE THAT HANDLES DROPZONE UPLOAD
      // 2. handlers should call `onUpload`
    },
    name: 'InputMultipleUpload',
    data () {
      return {
        files: [], // 1. declaring `files` here makes it reactive 
        showUploadProgress: true,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onUpload (file) {
        const meta = createdMeta = [{
          name: "caption",
          type: "text",
          value: ''
        }]
        this.files.push({file, meta}); // 3. push the new data onto the stack and the component will update
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
let createdMeta = formFields;
uploads.push({file,meta:createdMeta});
```

in a loop you actually just pass the reference to the same `formFields` array object and then binds all your inputs to it.

This is likely to work as it should, if you pass a new array copy for each input. You can do it easy this way:

```
let createdMeta = formFields.slice();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately that hasn't worked. Strange predicament but thanks anyway

Comment: @LewisCains, okay, then... can you inspect the value of the `formFields` at this step? In your code it is not shown where this variable gets the value. Is it actually an array the same as you assigned staticaly?

Answer (score 0):

```
let createdMeta = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(formFields))
```

Thanks to Rick in Slack, and Dave Steward too, I have refactoring to do but for the purpose of this thread here is the solution